# Best way to report comparisons of one agency to the rest of the state/nation

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting, ssas, analysis

When attempting to do some benchmarking type reports, I run into the issue of extreme slowness due to the amount of data residing in the database, and this will get incrementally worse.  I'm curious of what would be considered the best approach for reports that show for example a percentage of patients entering the hospital within a certain date range that were there due to a specific condition, as well as how that particular hospital compares to the state percentage and also the national percentage.  Of course this is all based on the hospitals whose data resides in the database.  I have just been writing stored procedures to calculate these percentages, but I know this isn't the best approach.  I'm curious how other more experienced reporting professionals would tackle this.  I'm currently using SSRS for reporting.  I know a little about SSAS, but not enough to know if I should consider it for this type of reporting.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on the data-structure and the kind of calculations you have to do.
You try to narrow down the amount of data you have to process and the complexity of operations in every possible way
If you have lots of data on a slow system you first try to select the needed data, transfer it to the calculation point and then keep it cached as long as you can.
If you have huge amounts of data you try to preprocess it as much as you can. E.g. for datawarehouses you have a datetime-table with year/month/day/day-of-week/week-of-year etc in it and just constraints to them in the other tables. Like this you can avoid timeconsuming calculations.
If the operations are complex you have to analyze them to make them simpler/faster but on this point it is impossible to predict how much (if at all) there is some room.

It all depends on your understanding of the data-structure and processes you need them for, in order to improve everything as much as you can.
I myself haven't worked with SSAS yet but this is also a great tool but (imho) more for lots of different analysis.